# Discriminate first and last element in each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@example.each do |e|
  #do something here
end
```

Here I want to do something different with the first and last element in each, how should I achieve this? Certainly I can use a loop variable i and keep track if `i==0` or `i==@example.size` but isn't that too dumb?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of the nicer approaches is:

```
@example.tap do |head, *body, tail|
  head.do_head_specific_task!
  tail.do_tail_specific_task!
  body.each { |segment| segment.do_body_segment_specific_task! }
end
```

Comment: this is the same essentially as the second part of @thomasfedb`s answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135002/410102)

Comment: @steenslag: I don't know. Somehow functional programming in general and Ruby `tap` in particular is all the rage lately. But I guess, yes, there is a reason: local variables head, body and tail cease to exist once the block job is done. That could be a very minor advantage.

Comment: Can anyone please point me to documentation for how `head,*body, tail = @example` works? Specifically the *b part? Many thanks!

Comment: @Matt: [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html), but they are [still squabbling](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8463). You will also do need a few paper books on Ruby, and not just as a status symbol.

Comment: This is one of the sickest bits of Ruby I've seen in a while. Elegant & functional(-ish).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `each_with_index` and then use the index to identify the first and last items. For example:

```
@data.each_with_index do |item, index|
  if index == 0
    # this is the first item
  elsif index == @data.size - 1
    # this is the last item
  else
    # all other items
  end
end
```

Alternately, if you prefer you could separate the 'middle' of the array like so:

```
# This is the first item
do_something(@data.first)

@data[1..-2].each do |item|
  # These are the middle items
  do_something_else(item)
end

# This is the last item
do_something(@data.last)
```

With both these methods you have to be careful about the desired behaviour when there are only one or two items in the list.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly common approach is the following (when there are certainly no duplicates in the array).

```
@example.each do |e|
  if e == @example.first
    # Things
  elsif e == @example.last
    # Stuff
  end
end
```

If you suspect array may contain duplicates (or if you just prefer this method) then grab the first and last items out of the array, and handle them outside of the block. 
When using this method you should also extract the code that acts on each instance to a function so that you don't have to repeat it:

```
first = @example.shift
last = @example.pop

# @example no longer contains those two items

first.do_the_function
@example.each do |e|
  e.do_the_function
end
last.do_the_function

def do_the_function(item)
  act on item
end
```

Comment: This will break if `@example` contains duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer @Matt.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) Often in rails this kind of behaviour is targeted at a database collection so normally duplicates are unlikely, but since OP doesn't state that I certainly shouldn't have assumed it.