# Iterate over n to last item in a Ruby enumerable

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find the cleanest way to do something special for the first item in an array, then do something different for all the rest. So far I have something like this:

```
puts @model.children.first.full_name
@model.children[1..@model.children.count].each do |child|
  puts child.short_name
end
```

I don't like how I have to specify the count in the range. I would like to find a shorter way to specify "from the second item to the last". How can this be done?

Comment: Duplicate of [Discriminate first and last element in each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134981/discriminate-first-and-last-element-in-each).

Comment: One thing to remember: In the search for "tight" code, it's easy to lose sight of readability and maintainability. It's very obvious what `[1..@model.children.count]` is doing. Finding alternate ways of doing the same thing shouldn't sacrifice that. Using `-1` is the most obvious short-cut to replace `@model.children.count`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby has a cool way of doing this with the splat operator `*`.  Here is an example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
first, *rest = *a
puts first # 1
puts rest # [2,3,4]
puts a # [1,2,3,4]
```

Here is your code rewritten:

```
first, *rest = @model.children
puts first.full_name
rest.each do |child|
  puts child.short_name
end
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: For me, pattern matching is so elegant. +1

Answer (score 6):

You can take this approach:

```
@model.children[1..-1].each do |child|
  puts child.short_name
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You might use `drop`:

```
puts @model.children.first.full_name
@model.children.drop(1).each do |child|
  puts child.short_name
end
```

Comment: is this a destructive action? or does drop return a copy?

Comment: @Andrew `drop` is not destructive.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?:

```
puts @model.children.first.full_name
@model.children[1..-1].each do |child|
  puts child.short_name
end
```

Comment: So close..., probably was what it took me to write the `puts` line :P

Comment: @JanDvorak What does mean - *FGITW* . I am stupid to understand short form.. :(

Comment: what that phrase mean? :))

Comment: Meta to the rescue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89713 (this is like answering a question inside a question)

Comment: Woww nice to know :))) You guys are awesome... Like it. *+1* to you.. to teach me the short form :D

Answer (score 0):

Your title says you want to omit `n` elements, but the OP text only asks for treating the first element specially. In case you are interested in the more general nanswer, here is one concise option:

```
n = 1 # how many elements to omit
@model.children.drop( n ).map( &:short_name ).each &method( :puts )
```

Comment: `puts @model.children.drop( n ).map( &:short_name )` would have worked too.

Comment: Would it? I'm not that familiar with the way puts handles its args, and I like to promote `&method( ... )` trick someone else taught me here on SO recently.

Comment: Yes, `puts` takes arrays and single elements. With arrays it iterates over them, putting each element on a single line. And, yes, `&method(...)` is a nice trick, but it's a shiny new hammer and not everything needs to be hit with it.

Comment: Thanks for explanations, especially on `puts`. Many times as I've used `puts`, I never bothered to read the doc or its source, I've remedied that thanks to you :-)))